# Loading 3rd party JS files to angular components files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have loaded 3rd party js file into app.component like this

```
declare var MarvinJS: any;
import { MarvinJS } from "../assets/js/marvinjslauncher.js";
```

can i use methods which are defined in the marvinjslauncher.js in my app component class, If yes can please guide me how to use? I have tried to use like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
      MarvinJS.MarvinJSUtil.getEditor("#sketch").then(function(sketcherInstance){
            });
}
```

If the way i am importing is wrong can you please guide me that too. And i have also included marvinjslauncher.js file into index.itml
I am getting this kind of errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'MarvinJSUtil' of undefined
    at new AppComponent (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:1312), <anonymous>:16:39)
    at createClass (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:11007:26)
    at createDirectiveInstance (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:10841:37)
    at createViewNodes (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:12204:49)
    at createRootView (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:12109:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:13247:42)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:12707:12)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:10030:46)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:3633:29)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:321), <anonymous>:5214:57)
```

Comment: using angular cli by chance ? import will not work if MarvinJS is not an ES module. You;ll have to add it to your page via a `<script>` tag. Then you dont need the import statement and the `MarvinJS` namespace will be available in your browser.

Comment: Try instantiating MarvinJS in your constructor and don't declare the var.

    constructor(private marvinJS: MarvinJS){}

Then try referring to this.marvinJS and see if you can get to the methods through that instance

Comment: @AhmedMusallam that's not true you can load a global dependency using `import 'dep';`

Comment: yes `import "../assets/js/marvinjslauncher.js"` is a static import. while `import { MarvinJS } from "../assets/js/marvinjslauncher.js";` is a module import. I did say that the import in the question will not work :) A static import is not recommended as it appears `MarvinJS` is needed globally.

Comment: Where does the term static import come from?

Comment: @Krish did you also remove this line: `import { MarvinJS } from "../assets/js/marvinjslauncher.js";`? is it added before your app's JS? Also, is the `MarvinJS` namespace available in browser console?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam i have added `marvinjslauncher.js` into `index.html` by `<script>` tag

Comment: @AhmedMusallam earlier `marvinjslauncher.js` there in `index.html` .
`MarvinJS` name space available in  browser console.
now i removed `import { MarvinJS } from "../assets/js/marvinjslauncher.js"` from `component.ts`. 
Then i getting this kind of error
`core.es5.js?0445:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Unable to get element with id: #sketch
    at resolvePromise (eval at <anonymous> (bundle.js:2805), <anonymous>:757:31)
    at resolvePromise (eval at <anonymous>`

Comment: And it still is not working?? Hmm strange.. unless i see your project setup and code, i'm out of ideas

Comment: @AhmedMusallam is any way for you to see my project setup and code?

Comment: @Krish Can you set up a github repo?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam here is the [GitHub Link](https://github.com/venkatakrishna874/angular4WithMarvinJS)

Comment: @Krish it seems to be working fine.. I dont get the error you are seeing, I get different errors. I fixed them and made a pull request. Let me know if this works for you and I can write a full answer. pull request here: https://github.com/venkatakrishna874/angular4WithMarvinJS/pull/1

Comment: It's working @AhmedMusallam Appropriated for help .

Comment: @Krish I added an answer, please accept it if it looks good. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion we had in the comments here are a few things to fix this issue and other issues in the code:

first, include your `MarvinJs` js file as a `<script>` and make sure you can access `MarvinJs` namespace and utils in the console.

then, in your app.component.ts file

```
declare var MarvinJS: any; // keep
// remove this import
//import { MarvinJS } from "../assets/js/marvinjslauncher.js";

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit { // implement AfterViewInit

  constructor() {} // remove MarvinJs code from constructor

  ngAfterViewInit(){
       // move MarvinJs code from constructor to ngAfterViewInit method. read about AfterViewInit here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html
       MarvinJS.MarvinJSUtil
      .getEditor("#sketch")
      .then(function(sketcherInstance){});
  }
```

Comment: Can i see any working example it will help me a lot, am new to angular